# Drupal 8 Get Child Pages

Tags: 8, navigation

So I am looking to fetch child page of current node for eg

```
Birds
 - Great Blue Heron
 - Wood Duck
 - Willet
Fish
 - Bass
 - Catfish
 - Tilapia
```

When I am on Bird page I would like to show
 - Great Blue Heron
 - Wood Duck
 - Willet

When I am Willet as Willet have no child pages it should show parent page and if do have child pages it should show its child pages

Is it possible to do it automatically like Admin creates a page he doesnt need to go to menu and add it himself to the menu , I tried https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block seems like there are 2 steps involved

1. Create Page
2. Than Add to Menu

I want to get Node id and automatically fetch its child and sub-child pages

Comment: You add a menu item right from the node page.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit ?

Comment: If the content type setting has enabled any menu placement, the. Those node forms have a section to add a menu link. It doesn't have to be a separate process.

Comment: I am sorry but I donot understand , DO you mean in a view I could arrange a filter in a way that I can get child pages of current page ?

Comment: What? You don't need views for any of this. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/working-with-menus/adding-a-link-to-a-menu

Comment: How exactly are you managing parent and child relationships? Unlike other CMS systems, Drupal has no hierarical content structure. Drupal usually works with reference fields to connect content. Creating a menu tree with references to nodes does not really connect the nodes in anyway beside the menu. Maybe try the book module to see if that provides what you're after.

Comment: Make Complete sense @Berdir . Thank you for your time and answer